# Passing Multiple Values in a Global Variable and print it during Runtime of BODS job

Tags: business-objects, sap-data-services

I am new to BODS and currently in my project I have a requirement where after the BODS job gets completed I have to send a mail alert to the user along with total how many IDOCs have been posted and their IDOC numbers.

So for IDOC number I have created a Global Variable and wrote the below code.

```
$GV_IDOC_NO = sql('DS_STG','SELECT DISTINCT IDOC_NO from table_xyz');
```

But with this I can see it is taking only 1 IDOC, if there are multiple IDOCs for one run it's sending the first IDOC number only.

Can someone help me how can I store multiple values in my Global Variable and then attach it to mail or infacat can test just by printing the value whether multiple values are printing or not?

Comment: What means "infacat"?

Comment: probably "in fact"